# Adding custom "3 section" footer to default report template

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

What is the best approach for creating a "3 section" (left, right, center) report footer in SSRS 2005?

I'm putting the `report ID and version number` in the bottom left hand corner- the `print (current) date/time` in the center and `page x of y` on the right.

Currently I simply place three overlapping text boxes with different alignment but I get warnings: `[rsOverlappingReportItems] The textbox ‘textbox28’ and the textbox ‘textbox19’ overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.`

What would a better way of doing this be?

Can I then modify the default template or add to the wizard so my new reports all include this?

Comment: Why not create three different text boxes without overlapping? Divide up the width of your report by three.

Comment: The text for the 3 boxes will likely not be the same length. I oversimplified a little in the question. But then again- maybe i'm overcomplicating it! The right hand textbox would always have to be the same width as the left hand box to ensure the text in the center box remains "centered". I suppose i'm just wondering if there's a better approach.

Comment: Or ignore the warning: see if the renderers you need support overlapping text boxes: if so, the warning is not a problem. I don't think there are many dramatically different options, even if you upgrade SSRS.

Comment: That was my first thought- but it only renders properly in BIDS. Comes out wrong in all browsers.

Comment: I'd go for the solution with three non-overlapping boxes as @Jamie said. If it works better for you, you can make the centered one larger than the two other. As long as left and right are equal in size, the middle one should be centered and you're able to handle longer strings in that box. I haven't encountered a simpler/alternative approach in getting that requirement to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this I'm answering the following part of your question:

> Can I then modify the default template or add to the wizard so my new
>   reports all include this?

You actually can modify the default template. The default template is actually just a simple report, a .rdl file.  It's located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject\

So what you need to do is create a report that will be your template, then replace the content of the Report.rdl with the content of your template report. You can right-click the report in Solution Explorer and select View Code to copy the content to clipboard (or use any text editor).

Alternatively, you can leave the default report.rdl as is, and add an additional .rdl in that folder which will serve as your template. Any .rdl added in that folder will appear when you do Add > New Item in Solution Explorer.

*(For SSRS 2008, the path above would be: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\ProjectItems\ReportProject)*

Answer (score 1):

As @Valentino said we can modify the default template globally or you can follow this procedure for modifying locally.
You can acheive this by.

create a report with what you need by default like having the Report header and Report Footer with the 3 textboxes and alignment and content in report footer textboxes and page margins if needed. Assume this as the template for all the reports.

Next in the solution explorer when you want to create the new report then right click on the report you created as the template and press copy. Click on the solution explorer area and press ctrl+v. This will create a copy of the report template.

Rename it and use it.