# swap image with set of textbox elements in rdlc report

Tags: rdlc

We are getting several RDLC warnings like the following.

The image ‘Image1’ and the text box ‘textbox’ overlap. Overlapping report items are not supported in all renderers.

I would like to find a way to design our reports so we do not get this warning, preferably without having to create different versions of the same report.

Scenario:

Our customer may provide us an image which shows their address and contact info, and in these cases we want to display that image in the top left of the report. When the customer does not provide an image, we want to display a series of text-boxes that provide the same information.

Right now we are putting these elements in the same report space and controlling visibility with expressions, which of course is giving us the warnings.

Comment: Are you able to dynamically insert the image at a specific pixel location? I've done this with other report builders - not sure if it's possible in this scenario?

Comment: We put both on the design surface at the same time and then dynamically showing/hiding ... are you thinking we should leave that space open on the designer and dynamically insert the image or all the controls?

Comment: Possibly? No experience with it, but if you can dynamically insert elements, I'd assume you could insert both images and textboxes, and drive the logic from the code.

Comment: Have you looked at the solution in
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750776/adding-custom-3-section-footer-to-default-report-template
?